# Dotfuscator netstandard project using Dotfuscator community only

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard-2.0, dotfuscator

Like the title says, im trying to use `Dotfuscator community` with netstandard project.

I have already Done so with xamarin project By folowing [this](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_protect.html#integrate-xamarin)

And it dose not really work with netstandard and net core project.

For net standard2.0 i tried using [this](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_protect.html#integrate-core) guid, but as im using the free version that are included in visual studio 2019. I cant find `PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Common.targets`

So do you know a setup with maybe a commandline or something, i could use.

> This is what i tried.
>   Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--This config file was generated by Dotfuscator. Please use the Dotfuscator Config Editor to modify.-->
<!DOCTYPE dotfuscator SYSTEM "http://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/dtd/dotfuscator_v2.5.dtd">
<dotfuscator version="2.3">
  <global>
    <option>debugauto</option>
  </global>
  <input>
    <loadpaths />
    <asmlist>
      <inputassembly refid="a1403c2e-befc-47f7-b609-503ab5bb2ab2">
        <option>honoroas</option>
        <option>stripoa</option>
        <option>library</option>
        <option>transformxaml</option>
        <file dir="E:\Projects\Youtube.Manager\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2" name="Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll" />
      </inputassembly>
    </asmlist>
  </input>
  <output>
    <!--<file dir="${configdir}\Dotfuscated" />-->
    <file dir="${configdir}\Dotfuscated" />
  </output>
  <renaming>
    <option>xmlserialization</option>
    <mapping>
      <mapoutput overwrite="true">
        <file dir="${configdir}\Dotfuscated" name="Map.xml" />
      </mapoutput>
    </mapping>
    <referencerulelist>
      <referencerule rulekey="{6655B10A-FD58-462d-8D4F-5B1316DFF0FF}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{7D9C8B02-2383-420f-8740-A9760394C2C1}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{229FD6F8-5BCC-427b-8F72-A7A413ECDF1A}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{2B7E7C8C-A39A-4db8-9DFC-6AFD38509061}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{494EA3BA-B947-44B5-BEE8-A11CC85AAF9B}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{89769974-93E9-4e71-8D92-BE70E855ACFC}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{4D81E604-A545-4631-8B6D-C3735F793F80}" />
      <referencerule rulekey="{62bd3899-7d53-4336-8ca2-4e5dbae187d5}" />
    </referencerulelist>
  </renaming>
  <sos mergeruntime="true">
    <option>version:v4</option>
    <option>sendanalytics</option>
    <option>dontsendtamper</option>
  </sos>
  <smartobfuscation>
    <smartobfuscationreport verbosity="all" overwrite="true" />
  </smartobfuscation>
</dotfuscator>
```

> Inside the project

```
  <Target Name="CustomAfterBuild" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" >
    <Message Text="Should run after build" Importance="High" />
    <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE\dotfuscatorCLI.exe&quot; Dotfuscator.xml" />
  </Target>
```

I get the error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3073 The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE\dotfuscatorCLI.exe" Dotfuscator.xml" exited with code 1.    Youtube.Manager.Models.Container    E:\Projects\Youtube.Manager\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.csproj    34
```

> The logg

```
1>Should run after build
1>Youtube.Manager.Models.Container -> E:\Projects\Youtube.Manager\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll
1>Should run after build
1>Dotfuscator Community Version 5.42.0.9514-e0e25f754
1>Copyright 2002-2019 PreEmptive Solutions, LLC All Rights Reserved.
1>Use of this software implies acceptance of accompanying license agreement.
1>
1>Dotfuscator Community Version 5.42.0.9514-e0e25f754
1>Copyright 2002-2019 PreEmptive Solutions, LLC All Rights Reserved.
1>Use of this software implies acceptance of accompanying license agreement.
1>
1>For personal use only. Please refer to the EULA distributed with The Software for details.
1>
1>For personal use only. Please refer to the EULA distributed with The Software for details.
1>
1>[Build Output] Loading Assemblies...
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] Loading Assemblies...
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\ildasm.exe /OUT=C:\Users\alent\AppData\Local\Temp\~Youtube.9\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll.il /TEXT /NOBAR /RAWEH /QUOTEALLNAMES /UTF8  /FORWARD E:\Projects\Youtube.Manager\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\ildasm.exe /OUT=C:\Users\alent\AppData\Local\Temp\~Youtube.11\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll.il /TEXT /NOBAR /RAWEH /QUOTEALLNAMES /UTF8  /FORWARD E:\Projects\Youtube.Manager\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] Read debugging symbols for module 'Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll'.
1>[Build Output] Read debugging symbols for module 'Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll'.
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] Processing instrumentation attributes...
1>[Build Output] Processing instrumentation attributes...
1>EXEC : [Build Output] warning : No SetupAttribute was found. Messages will not be sent for any configured analytics messages and/or checks.
1>EXEC : [Build Output] warning : No SetupAttribute was found. Messages will not be sent for any configured analytics messages and/or checks.
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] Analyzing Markup...
1>[Build Output] Analyzing Markup...
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] Renaming...
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] Renaming...
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] Updating Markup...
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] Updating Markup...
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] Writing map file to E:\Projects\Youtube.Manager\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container\Dotfuscated\Map.xml
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] Writing map file to E:\Projects\Youtube.Manager\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container\Dotfuscated\Map.xml
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] The process cannot access the file 'E:\Projects\Youtube.Manager\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container\Dotfuscated\Map.xml' because it is being used by another process.
1>[Build Output] Build Error.
1>[Build Output] Writing Assemblies...
1>[Build Output]
1>E:\Projects\Youtube.Manager\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.csproj(34,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE\dotfuscatorCLI.exe" Dotfuscator.xml" exited with code 1.
1>Done building project "Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>[Build Output] Running C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ilasm.exe /OUTPUT=C:\Users\alent\AppData\Local\Temp\~Youtube.9\stub-pdb\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll /nologo  /quiet /dll  /PDB /resource=C:\Users\alent\AppData\Local\Temp\~Youtube.9\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll.res C:\Users\alent\AppData\Local\Temp\~Youtube.9\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll.il
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] Wrote assembly "E:\Projects\Youtube.Manager\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll" to "E:\Projects\Youtube.Manager\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container\Dotfuscated\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll"
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] Build Finished.
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] Types Renamed:  21 of 81  (25.93%)
1>[Build Output] Methods Renamed:  50 of 454  (11.01%)
1>[Build Output] Fields Renamed:  219 of 307  (71.34%)
1>[Build Output]
1>[Build Output] You might see better renaming results by disabling Library Mode for one or more of your assemblies.
1>[Build Output] Please see https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/obfuscation_overview.html#library-mode
1>[Build Output] for additional information about enabling Library Mode and how to configure renaming exclusions.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. It seems like your target `CustomAfterBuild` is running twice somehow, as several logging lines are repeated, and the error appears to be related to multiple instances of Dotfuscator trying to write the [map file](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/obfuscation_renaming.html#map-file) at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MSBuild integration](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_protect.html) you mentioned is exclusive to Dotfuscator Professional.

Dotfuscator Community has a [separate integration exclusive for Xamarin apps](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/getting_started_xamarin.html), including those that reference .NET Standard libraries.

For other platforms, Dotfuscator Community only supports "post-build" scenarios, where you run Dotfuscator on already-built assemblies (`.dll` and `.exe` files).
You will need to use the [Dotfuscator Community user interface](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/getting_started_gui.html) to create a Dotfuscator config file (e.g., `Dotfuscator.xml`), specifying which assemblies should be [inputs to Dotfuscator](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/gui_inputs.html). You can then call the [Dotfuscator Community command line](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/getting_started_cli.html) from a custom step at the end of your build to produce protected versions of your assemblies.

(*Note*: I work for the Dotfuscator team and am answering this as part of my job.)

Comment: Thx for the help man, i read this command line but as i said im really new to this and the link your provided dose not go into detali as how to create this config file and how to trigger the command line etc from the project file. Could you please provide, a setup here or there. this will really helpfull to me and other.

Comment: and remember what im intressted in is the dll not the exe files

Comment: I update my Q please see above if you could help me understand why im getting this error.